# Help understanding proof of Theorem 12.22 in Rudin's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm having some trouble with the proof mentioned in the title, more specifically the argument that comes after equations $\left(11\right)$ and $\left(12\right)$. Rudin states

> \begin{equation}
> \tag{11} \int_{\Delta}\widehat{S} \widehat{T} d\mu_{x,y} = \langle STx, y\rangle = \int_{\Delta} \widehat{S}d\mu_{Tx, y}
> \end{equation}
>   Since $\widehat{A} = C(\Delta)$, it follows that 
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{12} \widehat{T}d\mu_{x,y} = d\mu_{Tx,y}
> \end{equation}
>   for every choice of $x$, $y$ and $T$. The integrals $\left(11\right)$ remain therefore equal if $\widehat{S}$ is replaced by $f$.

I have two issues with this statement.

1. Let us denote the space of bounded Borel functions $f : \Delta \to \mathbb{C}$ (normed by the supremum norm)  by $\:\mathcal{B}(\Delta)$. Equation $\left(11\right)$ tells us that the bounded linear functionals $\Lambda_{1}, \Lambda_{2} : \mathcal{B}(\Delta) \to \mathbb{C}$ given by
   \begin{equation}
   \Lambda_{1}(f) := \int_{\Delta} f \: \widehat{T}d\mu_{x,y} \qquad \Lambda_{2}(f):= \int_{\Delta} f \: d\mu_{Tx,y}
   \end{equation}
   coincide when restricted to the set $C(\Delta) \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\Delta)$. But why would they $\:``$remain therefore equal when $\widehat{S}$ is replaced by $f \in \mathcal{B}(\Delta)"$? This happens as a consequence of $\left(12\right)$ according to Rudin, which leads us to point 2.
2. What does $\left(12\right)$ mean in this context? I'm tempted to believe it means $``\widehat{T}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\displaystyle \frac{d\mu_{Tx,y}}{d\mu_{x,y}} "$. But this would only make sense if $\mu_{x,y}$ was a positive measure, which is not (recall that the hypothesis of the Radon-Nikodym theorem involve a complex measure $\nu$ which is absolutely continuous with respect to a $\sigma$-finite positive measure $\mu$). Invoking the Riesz representation theorem (theorem 6.19 in Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis) one could also argue that when we consider $\Lambda_{1}$ as a bounded linear functional $\Lambda_{1} : C(\Delta) \to \mathbb{C}$, it is represented by a unique regular complex Borel measure $\mu$. By virtue of $\left(11\right)$, we know that $\mu = \mu_{Tx,y}$. But then again, formula $\left(11\right)$ would only hold for *continuous functions*, and not necessarily for functions in $\mathcal{B}(\Delta)$, since $C(\Delta)$ is not dense in $\mathcal{B}(\Delta)$.

I'm afraid I might be missing something really elementary here, but I can't figure what it is.

Comment: Read (12) as $$\hat{T} \,d\mu_{x,y} = \hat{T} \frac{d\mu_{x,y}}{d\lvert\mu_{x,y}\rvert} \,d\lvert\mu_{x,y}\rvert = \frac{d\mu_{Tx,y}}{d\lvert\mu_{x,y}\rvert}d\lvert\mu_{x,y}\rvert$$ to take the RN-derivative with respect to a positive measure. But one can generalise the RN-derivative to complex measures, and then (12) really means $\hat{T} = \frac{d\mu_{Tx,y}}{d\mu_{x,y}}$.

Comment: Many thanks Mr. Fischer!

Comment: May be you can try with some Prittys